# C# and FAXCOMEXLib

Tags: c#, windows-vista, windows-xp

I'm using the FAXCOMEXLib api for sending faxes in C#.  I've recently moved to a new development machine running Vista and now I'm running into an issue with the API.  Microsoft released a new version with Vista and now when I compile the application on the Vista machine, I can't install and run it on an XP box without getting a fatal exception.

My question is, whats the best way to go about being able to compile and prepare installations on the Vista machine, but still allow the use of the application on XP?  Do I have to actually have an XP box available to do a final release compile or is there a way to get around these problems?

Thanks for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer but may help: 
I got this from Experts Exchange:

> After much tribulation, I found a
>   solution.
>
> The root cause of the problem is
>   simple: the version of FAXCOMEXLib in
>   Vista is different than that of XP.
>   So, when I built the solution in
>   Vista, it built the Interop wrapper
>   around the newer version, that found
>   in the system32 directory, regardless
>   of what actual fxscomex.dll file I
>   referenced. So, it was always wrapping
>   around a version of the file
>   incompatible with XP.
>
> To work around it, I built the
>   solution on an XP box, then stole the
>   Interop wrapper from that build. I
>   then wrote a batch file that I run
>   when I copy the build onto the XP box.
>   The batch file gets rid of the
>   existing Interop wrapper, replaces it
>   with the wrapper I stole from the XP
>   build, gets rid of my assembly (called
>   fax.dll) that references the Interop
>   wrapper, and recompiles it from
>   scratch on the XP box using the
>   csc.exe tool and the original fax.cs
>   file. In other words, I essentially
>   beat the files into submission until
>   they point to the right version of the
>   FAXCOMEXLib library. For clarity,
>   here's the batch file that converts
>   the Vista-compatible version of the
>   program to an XP-compatible version:
>
> ***** del Interop.FAXCOMEXLib.dll del fax.dll ren
>   Interop.FAXCOMEXLib.dll.fix
>   Interop.FAXCOMEXLib.dll
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc"
>   /t:library
>   /r:Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
>   /r:Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll
>   /r:Interop.FAXCOMEXLib.dll
>   /out:Fax.dll fax.cs
>
> ---
>
> Not very elegent or pretty, but it
>   does the trick.
>
> I would imagine that this would be an
>   issue with any old COM .dll on XP that
>   has been updated to a new version for
>   Vista.
>
> Thank you cpkilekofp for taking a
>   look. Admin, you may close this
>   thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ganesh.  I saw the same post but was hoping there was something simpler than that.  For now I'm likely just going to recompile the release objects on an XP machine until I can come up with a better solution.